# What's going on with this syntax "somename/.style={....}"

Tags: syntax, tikz-styles

I'm finding the following *preference* loading syntax popping up a lot in the newer packages:

From `tikz`

```
\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
```

From `tcolorbox`

```
\tcbset{noparskip/.style={before....}}
```

I assume this has something to do with LaTeX3, but I don't know where to go to read up on this and better understand the syntax.  I've looked at `expl3` but didn't find anything helpful there (truthfully, my head was spinning a bit just trying to understand the new syntax there).

Could someone point me in the right direction for a reference?

For example, reading the documentation of `xkeyval` helped immensely in creating my own environments to which I could pass *key values*.

How would I start writing my own code like

```
\aellettset{myexamquestion/.style={....}}
```

Comment: You can see the explanation in `Section 12.4` of the [pgf manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: @hpesoj626.  Thanks.  I think that's what I needed.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: IMHO, the complete and correct reference is "Key Management" (chapter 55 of the pgf manual v2.10)...

Comment: Crosslink, similar question [tikz pgf - What does /. mean exactly? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334783/what-does-mean-exactly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This "*preference* loading syntax comes from `tikz`. `tcolorbox` loads the package `tikz`. You can do this procedure with any `tikz`-based packages like

- the `tkz-collection` (`tkz-base`, `tkz-euclide`, etc.),
- `chemfig`,
- `tikz-timing`
- `hf-tikz`
- `mdframed` (loads `tikz` when needed, additionally defines `tikzsetting` option that passes options to `\tikzset`),

The explanation for this syntax can be found in `Section 12.4` of the `pgf manual` (for both version 2.10 and the 2.10-CVS versions). I quote from the manual (`version 2.10`):

> Many commands and environments of Tik Z accept options. These options are so-called key lists. To process the options, the following command is used, which you can also call yourself. Note that it is usually better not to call this command directly, since this will ensure that the effect of options are local to a well-defined scope.
>
> `\tikzset{<options>}`
>
> This command will process the options using the `\pgfkeys` command, documented in detail in Section 55, with the default path set to /tikz. Under normal circumstances, the options will be lists of comma-separated pairs of the form `key = value`, but more fancy things can happen when you use the power of the pgfkeys mechanism, see Section 55 once more.
>   When a pair `key = value` is processed, the following happens:
>
> 1. If the key is a full key (starts with a slash) it is handled directly as described in Section 55.
> 2. Otherwise (which is usually the case), it is checked whether `/tikz/` key is a key and, if so, it is executed.
> 3. Otherwise, it is checked whether `/pgf/` key is a key and, if so, it is executed.
> 4. Otherwise, it is checked whether key is a color and, if so, `color = key` is executed.
> 5. Otherwise, it is checked whether key contains a dash and, if so, `arrows = key` is executed.
> 6. Otherwise, it is checked whether key is the name of a shape and, if so, `shape = key` is executed.
> 7. Otherwise, an error message is printed.
>      Note that by the above description, all keys starting with `/tikz` and also all keys starting with `/pgf` can be used as key s in an options list.

### Edit

As mentioned by Paul Gaborit in comment for `tikz`, **Chapter 55, Key Management**, contains the complete reference for the `\tikzset` options. There is a direct link to this chapter from Section 12.4. In my copy of the version 2.10-CVS, it is found in Chapter 63.